# WriteLaTeX limited to 30 pages?

Tags: online, collaboration, overleaf

I've been experimenting with [WriteLaTex](http://writelatex.com/) and, while it seems to do a very nice job overall and has the best user experience of the alternatives I have tried, my experimental document stopped after 30 pages.  This does not happen on [shareLaTeX](http://www.sharelatex.com), [latexlab](http://docs.latexlab.org) or in my offline compiles of the same document on the Mac or the PC.  This led me to wonder whether a 30-page limit is built-in to WriteLatex?  I expect the example document to have a length of 34 pages.

As an aside, I also tried [SpanDex](http://www.spandex.io) but had other difficulties with it. By-and-large, I would like to stick with WriteLaTeX because, as I mentioned, its user experience seems the best to me.

Comment: I just tried with an document full of `\lipsum`. Even though the preview stopped at page 30, the exported PDF had 51 pages. Perhaps some bug in the previewer.

Comment: [This comment](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4386343) by one of the site developers suggests that the 30-page limit in preview is arbitrary, although full PDF export should work as expected.

Comment: We've recently lifted the document limits - see our blog post for more details (get 1GB of space for free!) https://www.writelatex.com/blog/6-no-more-document-limits

We've also added an FAQ section, which includes reference to the preview length:

https://www.writelatex.com/help/3-is-writelatex-limited-to-30-pages-the-preview-stops-at-that-point

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The preview seems to be limited to 30 pages for some reason. However, if you have a longer document, and export a PDF via the export-menu, that PDF will have all the pages.

There is a question about this in the feedback-forum. It is from April 2012, but no replies yet:

- http://writelatex.uservoice.com/forums/137318-feedback/suggestions/2811159-enable-the-preview-to-display-more-than-30-pages

As mentioned by Werner in [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89152/writelatex-limited-to-30-pages/89153#comment193547_89152), one of the developers has said that the 30-page limit is somewhat arbitrary:

- http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4386343

Comment: We've recently lifted the document limits - see our blog post for more details (get 1GB of space for free!) https://www.writelatex.com/blog/6-no-more-document-limits

We've also added an FAQ section, which includes reference to the preview length:

https://www.writelatex.com/help/3-is-writelatex-limited-to-30-pages-the-preview-stops-at-that-point

Answer (score 15):

One of the developers at [writelatex.com](https://www.writelatex.com) here. Firstly, thanks for using the site, glad you like the user interface; we're trying to make the experience as smooth as possible!

The 30-page limit on the preview is essentially arbitrary, as other posters have stated (and was posted by my co-developer on the HN comment) - it was the value we chose when originally developing the previewer. We've been working on a number of upgrades to the site recently, including improving the speed of preview refreshes, and are looking at the potential impact of lifting the preview page limit on server loads as the number of users keeps growing!

As was also already mentioned, the export to pdf should contain the full length document.

If you have a specific need for the longer preview drop us a line at our contact email address on our [About page](https://www.writelatex.com/about) & we'll see what we can do, and we hope you continue to enjoy using writeLaTeX :-)

Best,
John H

PS: Thanks for pointing out the unanswered uservoice forum post - we try to respond to all the posters in the feedback forum, but I now see a couple that we didn't (which I can now rectify).

Comment: Thanks much. The export-to-PDF works great and now that I understand the issue all is well.  May I suggest a prominent note on the site concerning the arbitrary page limit?  It's quite a reasonable thing to do, but caused me to question my document because I was loading in a lot of brittle legacy packages and wasn't sure whether I had a bug.

Comment: Glad to help, and your suggestion of adding a note about this to the site is a good one, thanks (we've been planning to add an FAQ section for a while now, but have focused on developing other features). This question has highlighted the need for an FAQ page for points like this.

Comment: We've recently lifted the document limits - see our blog post for more details (get 1GB of space for free!) https://www.writelatex.com/blog/6-no-more-document-limits

We've also added an FAQ section, which includes reference to the preview length:

https://www.writelatex.com/help/3-is-writelatex-limited-to-30-pages-the-preview-stops-at-that-point